# Automatically create route and html file with Python-Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a general question regarding Python and Flask. I'm trying to achieve below:

1. One a web page, there is a link called "create project" and a user can click on it.
2. Inside of the "create project" page, it's a form where the user can enter information such as project name, and then submit.
3. Once the form is submitted, it will automatically create an html file in the templates directory using the submitted information.
4. In the Python application, it automatically creates `@app.route()` for that html file (is this possible?).

I know how to do steps 1 and 2. Step 3 is a little tricky to me but I think I can read a base html file and then write it using `with open("filename.html", "r")` and `with open("filename_copy.html, "w")`, but there are probably better ways. I have no clue about how to do step 4 and this is what I'm really trying to figure out. The goal is to let a user create a project on the web page and then my application will automatically create a link for that project, and then that project will show up in the dashboard or something for the user to access it.

Thanks in advance!

Update on 04/30/2020:

Here is what I did eventually. In the HTML file, I created an "href" and used Jinja to take information from my Python application.

```
<a href="{{variable}}">{{variable}}</a>
```

And in the Python application, I created:

```
@app.route("/<current_project>")
def current_project(current_project):
    return render_template("{}.html".format(current_project))
```

If the "variable" gets passed in is called "project_1", it will direct me to route "/project_1", which is a dynamic link and it will then render "project_1.html", as long as the file exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add `dynamic routing` in `flask` and the code is as follows:

```
# you can also use a particular data type such as int,str
# @app.route('post/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('post/<variable>', methods=['GET'])
def daily_post(variable):
    #do your code here
    return render_template(f"{variable}.html")
```

Comment: use can use a `DB` or `excel` file etc.